# UTF-8 to ASCII conversion in java

Tags: java, utf-8

I have one string which contains UTF-8 character set format.

```
String str = "100ÂµF";
```

And my desire output of above string is "100µF"

I have checked on StackOverflow and i got below code

```
public static String decompose(String s) {
    return java.text.Normalizer.normalize(s, java.text.Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+","");
}
```

But, I got the output of above string was "100AµF"

Comment: UTF-8 is not a character set. It is one of several character encodings for the Unicode character set. UTF-16 is another. That's the one used by Java's text datatypes: String, char and Character.

Comment: Based on reading between the lines of your example code, it appears that your text is somehow mangled before being put into a String. Go upstream and solve that problem. Please [edit] your question if you want to provide details about the upstream process.

Comment: `"100ÂµF"` is the UTF-8 encoded form of `"100µF"`. Java strings are UTF-16 encoded. The only way you could have gotten `"100ÂµF"` in a `String` is if you *incorrectly* converted UTF-8 data to UTF-16 using an 8-bit charset *OTHER THAN* UTF-8. Don't do that! And don't try to fix `"100ÂµF"` **post**-conversion to get `"100µF"` (or for any other similarly broken string). Unless you can *positively* identity the incorrect charset that was used to break the data, guessing won't work 100% of the time. You need to fix the logic bug that caused you to get the erroneous `"100ÂµF"` in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).

The problem here is that your String was created from bytes, using an *incorrect charset* that assumes one byte is one character, like like [ISO 8559-1](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#ISO_8859_1).

But the bytes are not ASCII and they are not ISO 8859-1.  The bytes are a UTF-8 representation of text.

Do not replace any characters.  Do not normalize the string.  The only *correct* solution is to revert the incorrectly decoded String back to bytes, then correctly decode the bytes using UTF-8:

```
byte[] originalBytes = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

str = new String(originalBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: This is the only answer with the correct analysis. However, given the sample data, it is not definitive that ISO 8859-1 should be used to undo the damage. My system has 8 character encodings that would correct this sample: windows -1250, windows-1252, windows-1254, windows-1258, iso-8859-1, iso-8859-3, iso-8859-9, and iso-8859-15. At most, one of them could be correct. @dev22intellial, if you can't find the incorrect code, you could possibly feed in a comprehensive test dataset (say a file with bytes 0-255) and detect if it can be reversed by exactly one character encoding.

Comment: Alternatively, assuming the `String` was created by simply extending raw bytes to 16-bit chars without regard to any charsets, then you could just allocate a `byte[]` array of the same length and then truncate each 16-bit char back to an 8-bit byte.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `µ` char in ASCII, so you can't write it in ASCII.

Java *String*s are sequence of unicode characters (and are internally encoded in UTF-16), so the problem you have depends either on how you read this string or on how you write it.

Normally this thing are solved by creating an `OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream out, String charsetName)` or `InputStreamReader(InputStream in, String charsetName)` setting the correct character set.

So if for example you get your string from an UTF-8 encoded file, you should create a reader like this:

```
Reader in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream('some_file.txt'),"UTF-8")
```

Or if you are writing to an ISO-Latin-1 file you should create the Writer like this:

```
Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream('some_file.txt'),"ISO-8859-1")
```

Similar things can happen with HTTP request / response, depending on how the body of each is interpreted by either the application server or browser, if that's your case, then you add some detail to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with `µ` (U+00B5, MICRO SIGN) and `Â` (U+00C2, LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX). Both these characters belong to [Latin-1 Supplement unicode block](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/latin_supplement/index.htm).

If you want to allow `µ` but disallow `Â` you have to do the filtering yourself. There won't be a separate character group (`\p{}`) for each of the characters.

One way to do it is to define a white-list filter:

```
String input = "100ÂµF";
String allowedFilter = "[^\\p{ASCII}µ]"; // regular ASCII + µ sign
String output = input.replaceAll(allowedFilter, "");
System.out.println(output); // 100µF
```

Do note that both `µ` and `Â` can be represented in [Extended ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) so filtering one and not the other is counter intuitive.